# How to define a NotesXspDocument Object in JAVA

Tags: java, xpages

In a JAVA bean that I am working on I want to pass a NotesXspDocument (could use a NotesDocument) to a method which looks like this:

```
public List<String>  getReaders(NotesXspDocument thisXspDoc){
// do some stuff

}
```

But JAVA does not recognize the NotesXspDocument definition. I have imported the following packages:

```
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.Document;
```

Is there a further package to import to make use the NotesXspDocument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on Jesses answer: in your case you need to do this to work with the XPages version of Document:

```
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument;

public List<String> getReaders(DominoDocument thisXspDoc){
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

NotesXspDocument is an SSJS-only alias; the real class is `com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument`: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html